# Asp.net c# - Checking if file exist failed

Tags: c#, .net, file-io

I have a project where I want to check if a file exist in a directory.

```
if (File.Exists("\\Galerija\\" + Session["up_ime"] + "\\" + Session["slika_profila"]))
{
  Label1.Text = "exist";
}
else {
  Label1.Text = "does not exist";
}
```

The directory of the file is `\Galerija\admin\slika.jpg`. The file is in the directory, but I get returned that it doesn't. I also printed the path I give to `File.Exists()` to the label and it should be correct. 
I don't see what is the problem. -The file should be found.

Comment: I tried also with the "FileInfo fi = new FileInfo("\\Galerija" + Session["up_ime"] + "\\" + Session["slika_profila"]);" and "fi.exists" but the same problem

Comment: You're probably getting the relative path wrong. Try an absolute path.

Comment: Is `Galerija` in the application's directory?

Comment: Absolute path works, but i would need a relative path... Galerija is in the applications directory, yes.

Comment: Then you're definitely getting the relative path wrong. Fix that and you're good to go. What's the issue with this solution? We don't know your folder structure so this is pretty difficult to answer.

Comment: I have a project "Galerija_template" folder where i keep another folder "Galerija", inside of this is "admin" folder and the there is a file I'm looking for. 
 I used the same relative path for putting images to the site.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In your comments you mentioned this is web site. So try with [**`Server.MapPath`**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms524632%28v=vs.90%29.aspx)

```
if (File.Exists(Server.MapPath(string.Format("Galerija/{0}/{1}" ,Session["up_ime"] , Session["slika_profila"]))))
{
     Label1.Text = "exist";

}
```

Answer (score 1):

Your relative path should be incorrect, Use Server.MapPath("your relative path to root folder") instead of direct relative path,

In your case, use

```
if (File.Exists(Server.MapPath("\\Galerija\\" + Session["up_ime"] + "\\" + Session["slika_profila"])))
        {
            Label1.Text = "exist";

        }
        else
        {
            Label1.Text = "does not exist";
        }
```

You can find more info here,

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httpserverutility.mappath.aspx

Answer (score 0):

If you're still not able to figure out what is wrong, you should use procmon.exe to find out the path that the file is being looked up at. It will also show you the errors if there are any. procmon outputs a lot of information, but the filter functionality can help you here.

Download it here - http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896645.aspx